# Extract a rotation matrix from a 3D transformation matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I've made a piece of code with some informations I found on the internet about matrix. But I'm stuck with the extraction of the rotation matrix from SRT.

```
def getRotationMatrix (m):
    scale = m.getScale() #return a Vector4 with the length of every row
    scaleMatrix = PMatrix4() #Initialize the scale matrix 
    for x in xrange (4):
        scaleMatrix[x,x] = scale[x] # set the scale factors on the diagonal
    rm = m*scaleMatrix.inverse() # and multiply the SRT matrice by the inverse
    return rm
```

Seems to work fine in most of the cases, but for example for this input:

```
m = [-12.175876450247891, 5.807595155923971, 19.849933782589485, 0.0], [-13.991742515447003, -19.27618605313048, -2.9427525595147523, 0.0], [-15.230862551074761, 13.065239750956977, -13.165118161273075, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

This return me a wrong result, the 3rd row is negative.
I'am wrong somewhere ?

Comment: That math you are relying on here seems bogus to me. But maybe I have misunderstood what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I'm just trying to extract a scale matrix, without rotation (and translation). (i've inversed "rotation" and "scale")

Comment: A scaling matrix is diagonal, but the scaling done by an arbitrary matrix is usually not axis aligned. You seem to be assuming it is?

Comment: what is `getScale()`?

Comment: Do you know the Scale and Translate amounts?

Comment: Take a look at [transformations.decompose_matrix](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html#line-717), which gives you the Euler `angles`. The rotation matrix can then be calculated by `transformations.euler_matrix(angles[0], angles[1], angles[2], 'sxyz')`